# Форматирование кода в PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

В общем, делаю презентацию, где будет много фрагментов кода.

Собственно вопрос:

А как это красиво можно оформить в  PowerPoint?

Если делать Copy/Paste из Visual Studio, то получается стремно+ может порушиться форматирование.

Если делать скриншоты кода, то тоже как-то не очень смотрится, особенно, если нужно несколько разных участков кода в 1 слайд засунуть.

Может кто-нибудь имеет в этом опыт и может подсказать к чему пришли, что бы код отображался добротно?

Comment: https://github.com/Eugeny/instacode )

Answer (score 0):

Лично я форматировал код вручную, выделяя ключевые слова жирным (как в подсветке синтаксиса). Фрагменты были небольшими, так что проблем не возникло.